# Programatic implications of ? vs no?

Tags: php, symfony

Working with Symfony for quite awhile now i've noticed something that I realized I never had an answer too. In Symfony it's not uncommon to see:

```
public function build(string $json): ?IntegrationErrors
```

But at the same time you can easily see:

```
public function build(string $json): IntegrationErrors
```

The thing is, as far as I can tell they do the same thing, there's no errors or warnings either way, so that brings me to the question of what are the programatic implications of using ? vs no ? when defining a return type?

Is this something specific to doctrine, as you tend to see it most inside of the Entities?

Comment: Can the return value be null? If yes, use `?`, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is excusive new feature of php 7.1

**[Nullable types](https://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)**

Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark. This signifies that as well as the specified type, NULL can be passed as an argument, or returned as a value, respectively.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, I couldn't seem to find that for the life of me. I guess you had to know what you were looking for!